# I cannot debug in Xamarin due to "Could not restore package" in the Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I would like to ask to help to solve the issue I met. 
Before, I accidentally deleted the Folder "bin" and "obj". then I found Xamarin didnt work. 
Then I re-installed the Xamarin soft ware. after that, I debug it.

It shows "Could not restore packages".

In the package console, it shows :

Getting restore information for project /Users/chunszeyeung/Projects/Testing1/Testing1.iOS/Testing1.iOS.csproj
/Users/chunszeyeung/Projects/Testing1/Testing1.iOS/Testing1.iOS.csproj(126,11) : error MSB4226: The imported project "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/6.6.0/lib/mono/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.CSharp.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/" and "/Applications/Visual Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/docker/MonoDevelop.Docker/MSbuild" . These search paths are defined in "/Users/chunszeyeung/Library/Caches/VisualStudio/8.0/MSBuild/326_1/MonoDevelop.MSBuildBuilder.exe.config". Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.
Unable to create package spec for project. '/Users/chunszeyeung/Projects/Testing1/Testing1.iOS/Testing1.iOS.csproj'

I recapped the pic of Xamarin attached

[Pic of Xamarin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpYNN.png)

Could any one help me to fix it ?

Thanks

Comment: Does that error occur on iOS and Android too? And does it not work for a new solution anyway

Answer (score 1):

The .obj and .bin files are removed after clicking the clear solution option, so do not look for the problem in deleting these folders only in the missing packages (probably restore nugets will help) or clear solution and then restart VS.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description , I am not sure about exact problem. I should suggest you check your network proxies ,if selected then deselect proxies and apply.

Select **Top solution > Right click > Restore nugets.**